# rewrite php get variable to another get variable

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have recently changed my site source code and everything is tested and works as expected but I have many legacy links from other places that I would like redirecting.

my old site used a link like

mypage.php?id=abc123

i need this to redirect to

mypage.php?user=abc123

thanks for anyone that can help ive tried different things but cant figure it out

I would have just changed the $_GET variable in the php file but its encrypted

Comment: You can use rewrite rles in your .htaccess if mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is installed but im not sure how to write the rule ive tried many variations but none seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You would use something like this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^mypage\.php\?id=(.*)$ mypage.php?user=$1 [L,R=301]
```